# Ошибка при компиляции с CLang

Tags: c, sublime-text-3, clang

Хотел скомпилировать код на Си с помощью CLang. Скачал, установил, в PATH добавил (У меня Win7).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пользуюсь Sublime Text 3, сделал новую Build System (пользуюсь недавно, по этому сделал с помощью найденного в интернете).

MyC.sublime-build

```
{
   "cmd": ["clang", "-std=c11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
   "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
   "working_dir": "${file_path}",
   "selector": ["source.c", "source.h"],
   "shell": true,
   "encoding": "utf-8",
   "variants":
     [
       {
         "name": "Run",
         "cmd": ["clang", "-std=c11", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}", "&&", "start", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"],
         "shell": true
       }
     ]
}
```

И, собственно, проблема:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to
>   see invocation)

Comment: если руками делать, то все то же самое. Та же ошибка :(

Comment: Я не ставил руками clang. С официального сайта скачал установщик и он сам всё сделал.

Comment: есть какая-нибудь инструкция ?

Comment: Побробуй скачать Clang x32, а не x64.